# How to use Bootstrap in custom master page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, branding, custom-masterpage, boot-strap

I have created html page for branding using bootstrap3. Now when I want to use the same in share point 2013 as master page it is overriding the MS classes and design.

Can any one suggest which is the best way to use bootstrap3 for share point 2013 custom master page.
[image]

Thannks

Answer (score 1):

In the custom masterpage add a css reference like below in the `<head>` tag after the corev15.css is loaded :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/bootstrap.min.css">
```

If you want to ensure that your css is loaded after SharePoint's css is loaded, use it like below in the `<head>` tag:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" ID="customcss1" Name="path/bootstrap.min.css" After="corev15.css" />
```

Also, the bootstrap js file should be loaded at the bottom of masterpage to ensure page speed, just above the `</body>` tag like below:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="path/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I applied CSS and javascript in the same way but it is overriding the MS Styles and change styling of page layout too. see image added in the question.