# Set Sidebar to fixed %

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am using the sharepoint page layout with the sidebar. In designer I can see that the column spacing is set to 33.3% but when I type in the main section, the sidebar gets squished. How can I set the sidebar to always remain at 33% of the page size and then have the main section fill the rest of the page?

```
class="ms-wiki-columnSpacing" style="width&#58;33.3%
```

Edit: Interestingly this issue doesn't happen on all resolutions or in Chrome. It does occur in IE. I am not sure how that is possible since its a percent of the page width.

Answer (score 0):

Add Bootstrap to a new/custom master page. You can find more details on the adding [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196941/how-to-use-bootstrap-in-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013). Bootstrap can make a page quite responsive to resizing across multiple browsers.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" ID="customcss1" Name="path/bootstrap.min.css" After="corev15.css" />
```